# How do i append another list within list comprehension

Tags: for-comprehension

I am trying to find out unique elements and avoid duplicates , between the lists (using list comprehension)

```
`a = [10 , 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89,9]`
`b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]`
```

`dup_list = []`

### This works , but with duplicates

```
`final_list = [uniq for uniq in a if a not in dup_list if uniq in b ]`
```

when i try to append the my dup_list in the last line of the comprehension statement it says invalid syntax
i.e this doesn't work.
"final_list = [uniq for uniq in a if a not in dup_list if uniq in b dup_list.append(uniq) "
I am a newbie in python so apologize for any missed out basic facts .

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [10, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 9]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
nodupes = sorted([item for item in a if item not in b] + 
                 [item for item in b if item not in a])
```

That yields `[4, 6, 7, 11, 12, 21, 34, 55, 89]`

Which is the same answer I get using sets:

```
seta = set(a)
setb = set(b)
nodupes = sorted(list(seta ^ setb))
```